# How to upsert nested tables values in Hasura GraphQL?

Tags: graphql, hasura

wanted to ask if it is possible to upsert nested objects? for example, if i have a 'Users' table and a 'Students' table, and I'm inserting a new User(with a taken id), i want to update all fields (using on_conflict and update_columns) including the fields in the 'Students' table.
Basically replace all user's fields except the primary key.

```
mutation($UsersData: [core_users_insert_input!]!) {
    insert_core_users(
      objects: $UsersData
      on_conflict: {
        constraint: core_users_id_unique
        update_columns: [first_name, last_name, gender]
      }
    ) {
      affected_rows
    }
  }
```

The **update_column** array should include fields from the 'Students' table but i can't figure it out.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, relevant documentation is here: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/upsert.html#upsert-in-nested-mutations

It is possible to use `on_conflict` key on any level (top, or nested) where you want to resolve updating an existing record.

```
mutation upsert_author_article {
  insert_author(
    objects: [
      {
        name: "John",
        articles: {
          data: [
            {
              title: "Article 3",
              content: "Article 3 content"
            }
          ],
          on_conflict: {
            constraint: article_title_key,
            update_columns: [content]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  ) {
    affected_rows
  }
}
```

Comment: i mean, is it possible to edit the 'articles' table when a constraint on 'author' table is broken.

Comment: It may be possible (but not sure I fully follow your example - please specify the schema and desired request more) - since you can set update_columns: [] on authors conflict, and then continue updating nested data (articles) if there is another conflict which you can force by submitting the primary key in the data payload which will conflict against the primary key constraint.  some more info: https://hasura.io/docs/1.0/graphql/manual/mutations/upsert.html#ignore-request-on-conflict